# Passing values of joined tables into function arguments

Tags: sql, informix

I wonder if there is a way to pass an argument to a function taken from a joined table value using informix (IDS 12.xx)

Let me explain this situation using code:

```
-- we have 2 tables with some values
create table tab1 (
    c1 int,
    c2 varchar(10)
);

insert into tab1 values ( 1, 'one' );
insert into tab1 values ( 2, 'two' );

create table tab2 (
    c1 int,
    c2 varchar(10)
);

insert into tab2 values ( 1, 'one' );
insert into tab2 values ( 2, 'also two' );
```

then we have a function with 1 argument

```
create function myfunc( myarg int )
returning varchar(10);
    define ret1 varchar(10);
    foreach cur for
        select c2 into ret1
        from tab2 where c1 <= myarg
        return ret1 with resume;
    end foreach;
end function;
```

Now, let's run some queries:

```
-- we can build this function into a select statment:
select * from table( function myfunc( 3 ) ) as myfunctab2( c2 );

-- we can also join tab1 into this select statment
select * from tab1
join table( function myfunc( 2 ) ) as myfunctab2( c2 ) on myfunctab2.c2 = tab1.c2;

-- but trying to add a column from the joined table as an argument fails
select * from tab1
join table( function myfunc( tab1.c1 ) ) as myfunctab2( c2 ) on myfunctab2.c2 = tab1.c2;
```

How can I tell `myfunc` to take its argument value from `tab1.c1`?

I know that the example would work just by replacing the function argument with an addtional return value and then just add it to the `ON...`  section of the query, but because this is just a reduced example it is not an option for me.

Any help would be very appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that Informix expects to evaluate the JOIN TABLE(FUNCTION myfunc(tab1.c1))` clause once, but to satisfy your query, if has to be executed multiple times, once for each value of `tab.c1`.  The fact that you're using Informix 12.10 complicates things; you can't use a CTE (common table expression) to help out — that feature was added in 14.10.  I'm not sure it will help, but it is an avenue I've not explored since it is not available to you.  I think you are likely to need to create a new function, `myfunc2`, which processes both `tab1` and `tab2` with a single statement.